# Multiple one-time PHP database updates using jquery's .error()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a webpage with some broken images, these images are being show by a database. I am using the following jQuery to hide the images that are broken.

```
//images are wrapped in an anchor
$("img").error(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

I would like to utilize the "status" column in the database to set all of the broken images to "hidden". Every anchor that wraps an image on the page has a "id" attribute that matches the primary database key "id".

```
$("img").error(function() {
    var error = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "changestatus.php",
        data: "status=hidden&id=".error.""
    });
});
```

// changestatus.php

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "stackoverflowexampleuser", "stackoverflowexamplepass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("stackoverflowexampledatabase") or die(mysql_error());
$id = $_POST['id'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$query="UPDATE stackoverflowexampletable SET status = '".$status."' WHERE id ='".$id."'";
mysql_query($query) or die ('error');
mysql_close();
header( 'Location: MYSOURCE' ) ;
?>
```

This is my first stab at ajax, and I know I got some stuff seriously wrong. I saw a couple of examples using KEY VALUE pairs but I don't know what the $_POST['var'] should be.

Can you even request something like this "when the page loads"? I tried wrapping it in an arbitrary button and it didn't work.

Since this just needs to be used once **I'm not really focused on using AJAX**.

Comment: No, although I'm new to debugging ajax with firebug. Nothing is really happening at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("img").error(function() {
    var error = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "changestatus.php",
        data: {
             status: "hidden",
             id: error
        }
    });
});
```

If you're wanting to initiate it on page load, be sure to include it in the `$(document).ready()` function.